# OrderCloud portal - Dashboard dark mode

Tags: ordercloud

I have just started working with the OrderCloud product.

How can I set the OrderCloud portal dashboard to dark mode?

I did not see any settings or options to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for dark mode for the OrderCloud portal.